# How do i store pictures in moodle?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I'm trying to create my own Activity in moodle where students can take pictures of their Drivers License and that pictures get stored in moodle, then later opended and shown to the teacher.

My Problem is to store the picture on the moodle side and not downloading it.(like i'm doing right now)

Hopfully someone can help me figure out a way to use the file_storage given by moodle to safe the pictures.

kind regards
J

This is my code for now (view.php) ... I know its not realy in a moodle way but im trying to get it to work first then then clean up the code

```
require_once('../../config.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/mod/driverslicense/lib.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/mod/assign/locallib.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/mod/driverslicense/classes/submit/submit.php');
require_once("$CFG->libdir/formslib.php");


$id = required_param('id', PARAM_INT);

list ($course, $cm) = get_course_and_cm_from_cmid($id, 'driverslicense');

require_login($course, true, $cm);

$context = context_module::instance($cm->id);

require_capability('mod/driverslicense:view', $context);

$driverslicense = new assign($context, $cm, $course);
$urlparams = array('id' => $id,
    'action' => optional_param('action', '', PARAM_ALPHA),
    'rownum' => optional_param('rownum', 0, PARAM_INT),
    'useridlistid' => optional_param('useridlistid', $driverslicense->get_useridlist_key_id(), PARAM_ALPHANUM));

$url = new moodle_url('/mod/driverslicense/view.php', $urlparams);
$PAGE->set_url($url);

// Update module completion status.
$driverslicense->set_module_viewed();

// Apply overrides.
$driverslicense->update_effective_access($USER->id);

// Get the driverslicense class to
// render the page.
//echo $driverslicense->view(optional_param('action', '', PARAM_ALPHA));
$mform = new submit();


echo $OUTPUT->header();

echo '<body>
    <div id="container">
        <video autoplay="true" id="video"></video>
        <button id="btn"> Take Picture </button>
        <canvas id="canvas" class="hidden"></canvas>
        <a id="dl-btn" href="frontpic" download="image.png" class="hidden"></a>
    </div>
</body>';



$fs = get_file_storage();

// Prepare file record object
$fileinfo = array(
    'contextid' => $context->id, // ID of context
    'component' => 'mod_driverslicense',     // usually = table name
    'filearea' => 'driverslicense',     // usually = table name
    'itemid' => 0,               // usually = ID of row in table
    'filepath' => '/',           // any path beginning and ending in /
    'filename' => 'driverslicensefront.png'); // any filename


$fs->create_file_from_url($fileinfo, imgURL );


echo $OUTPUT->footer();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const video = document.querySelector('#video')
    const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas')


    if ('mediaDevices' in navigator && 'getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
        .then(stream => {
            video.srcObject = stream
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('An error occured while accessing webcam.')
        })
    }

    btn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        const width = video.videoWidth, height = video.videoHeight
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

        canvas.width = width
        canvas.height = height

        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height)
        const imgURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')

        document.querySelector('#dl-btn').href = imgURL
        document.querySelector('#dl-btn').click()
    })

</script>
```

Comment: Use the "filemanager" element in a form, file_prepare_standard_filemanager() before displaying the form, and file_postupdate_standard_filemanager() after the form has been submitted - see https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms

Comment: @RussellEngland im fairly new to moodle development i dont realy understand how to do it. Is there a way you can show me how i can integrate this in my code?
Also i dont know how to get the information out of the <a> container and put ihem into a variable to safe it.

Comment: That would be a lot of code, which is why I made a comment - search the Moodle code for the functions above then have a go first - eg: /blog/edit.php and /blog/edit_form.php